# php mysql select multiple values from one table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to access a MySQL DB using PHP. I need to retrieve 6 values from my `actor_id` table displaying them in a html table. My SELECT statement is:

```
SELECT actor_id.actor_name, FROM actor_id WHERE movie.star1 = actor_id.actor_id;
```

Now how can I add another movie.star2, movie.star3 etc.??

DB Structure

NAME - fields
movie - movie_id title star1 star2
actor_id - actor_id actor_name

Comment: Please show your database structure. Do you really have a table called actor_id? And since you do not join anything how do you can use movie.star1? This should throw a syntax error.

Comment: Commas, commas, commas, and do you  really have a table called something_id? i think it's time to go back to [My]SQL 101

Comment: Is "actor_id" your table name or is it a column?

Comment: More info needed! Check comments below Fluffeh's answer (and perhaps check both his and my answer) because with your question as it now stands, there's about 1904338473294 possible answers...

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of this, you are actually using two tables here. Your query however only references one of them.

I think that you need something like this:

```
SELECT 
    actor_id.actor_name, 
FROM 
    actor_id 
        join movie
            on movie.star1 = actor_id.actor_id
            or movie.star2 = actor_id.actor_id
            or movie.star3 = actor_id.actor_id
            -- etc etc
```

On that note though, you would probably do really well to [read this lengthy Q&A that I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) to explain these things in a lot more detail.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to join actor_id on `movie`, since the `actor_id` row selected depends on which `movie.star1` values are being used?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Quite possibly, I am guessing at the table structure though and trying to use the inputs in the question :)

Comment: Of course, there's not enough info to give a definitive answer. I've read the question a second time... I've added a sub-query example to my answer, because (based on info provided by OP) that might be what he's looking for, too...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem +1 from me :)

Comment: +1 right back... my answer is getting rather tltr, and probably unintelligable for the OP, or besides the point

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Hehehe, you think that's long? Take a gander at the link in my answer. I had to post under multiple answers just to get it in there...

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, it's quite easy (if you [read the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)):

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 AS altName, lastFieldNoCommaHere
    FROM table
WHERE someField = 'value'
  AND id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
  AND (dateField > NOW()
       OR dateField IS NULL);
```

RTM and don't use `mysql_*` extension, it's deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`, not just because of the deprecation issue, [But for various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli).

Seing as you're using `movie.star1` in your where clause, you should look into [the `JOIN` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), too:

```
SELECT actor_id.name 
FROM actor_id
    LEFT JOIN movie
       ON movie.star1 = actor_id.actor_id
WHERE actor_id.actor_id IN (1,2,4,5,6,7,8,123);
```

That's, probably, what you're after, or perhaps:

```
SELECT actor_id.name
FROM actor_id
WHERE actor_id.actor_id
          IN ( SELECT movie.star1
                  FROM movie
                  WHERE movie.release_date >= '2012-01-01');
```

This is an example of a sub-query. Be careful with this, because it's often quite slow...
And as Fluffeh pointed out to me, you can't select multiple values, and have to resort to something like this:

```
SELECT actor_id.name
FROM actor_id
WHERE actor_id.actor_id
          IN ( SELECT IFNULL(movie.star1, IFNULL(movie.star2, movie.star3))
                  FROM movie
                  WHERE movie.release_date >= '2012-01-01');
```

Or:

```
SELECT actor_id.name
FROM actor_id
WHERE actor_id.actor_id
          IN ( SELECT IF (movie.star1 <= 12,
                          IF (movie.star2 <= 15,
                              movie.star3,
                              movie.star2),
                          movie.star1)
                  FROM movie
                  WHERE movie.release_date >= '2012-01-01');
```

Comment: You can't use multiple columns in a `in (select...)` subquery though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the or statement. 
I don't know your db structure but should looks like this with the or:

```
SELECT actor_id.actor_name,
FROM actor_id 
WHERE (movie.star1 = actor_id.actor_id or movie.star2 = actor_id.actor_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT actor_id.actor_name
FROM actor_id WHERE actor_id.actor_id in [specify the values like movie.star2, movie.star3... etc];
```

But can not use the comma before FROM ..